# Cycle through audio using js

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to use a button to change the audio track to 1 of 2 being played in the browser, however, the method I found switches to the second track but doesn't change the audio played afterwards, it only restarts the second track. Here's my code:

```
function loadSong(){
  var player=document.getElementById('player');
  var source1=document.getElementById('player');
  var source2=document.getElementById('player');

  source1.src='/audio/mac+.mp3';
  source2.src='/audio/mac-slowed.mp3';

  player.load(); //just start buffering (preload)
  player.play(); //start playing
}
```

HTML

```
<audio id="player" autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" loop="loop">
  <source id="source1" src="/audio/mac+.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source id="source2" src="" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<button onclick='loadSong()'>Switch the Music!</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you provided in your original inquiry, this is most likely the best fit for you.  Attached is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7sck396/2/) for you review.  You will need to update the `src` files with your own locally stored files.

**HTML:**

```
<audio id="source1" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" src='http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major.mp3'></audio>
<audio id="source2" loop="loop" src='http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Pachelbel%20-%20Canon%20in%20D%20Major.mp3'></audio>
<button id="player">Switch the music to track # 2</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var player = document.getElementById('player');
var source1 = document.getElementById('source1');
var source2 = document.getElementById('source2');

player.onclick = function() {
  curTrack = this.innerHTML.replace(/Switch the music to track # /, "");
  if (curTrack == "1") {
    nextTrack = "2";
    source1.play();
    source2.pause();
    source2.currentTime = 0;
  } else {
    nextTrack = "1";
    source2.play();
    source1.pause();
    source1.currentTime = 0;
  }
  this.innerHTML = "Switch the music to track # " + nextTrack;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the `#player` element look at your code you are saving the same selector to source1 and source 2 so change the selector of source one to `source1` and `source2`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean, could you elaborate? Should I change the IDs of source1 and source2 in the js to source1 and source2 like in the HTML?

Comment: @blackjackrobo look at your first 3 lines they are selecting the exact same element in the DOM. They need to select different elements or they will just keep replacing the src of the `#player` element